# Angular 4 + Angular Material 2 Template Form field validation not working

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular-validation

I have a search field which displays drop down with dynamic content. I want to be able to show a pattern validation error. Here is the code:

```
<md-input-container class="search-container">
  <input mdInput
         validateField
         [(ngModel)]="currentSearchResult"
         [disabled]="tdDisabled"
         (keyup)="performSearch(currentSearchResult)"
         [mdAutocomplete]="searchAuto" placeholder="{{'COMPANY.SEARCH' | translate}}">
  <md-error *ngIf="currentSearchResult.touched && currentSearchResult.invalid">
    <span *ngIf="currentSearchResult.errors.pattern">
      Invalid characters used.
    </span>
  </md-error>
</md-input-container>
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'touched' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (SearchComponent.html:8)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.es5.js:13058)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12238)
    at callViewAction (core.es5.js:12603)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.es5.js:12535)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12244)
    at callViewAction (core.es5.js:12603)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.es5.js:12535)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12244)
    at callViewAction (core.es5.js:12603)
```

Which points to this line:

```
<md-error *ngIf="currentSearchResult.touched && currentSearchResult.invalid">
```

I don't quite understand why they variable is not defined. I tried using the `ngModel name="currentSearchResult"` and `#currentSearchResult="ngModel"` but that gave also errors.

What am I missing with this field?
Thanks

Comment: can You provide Your `.ts` file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this syntax (I removed some parts for the clarity)

```
<md-input-container class="search-container">
  <input mdInput
         [(ngModel)]="currentSearchResult"
         required
         name="myModel" 
        #myModel="ngModel">


  <md-error *ngIf="myModel.touched && myModel.invalid">
    <span *ngIf="myModel.errors.required">
      Invalid characters used.
    </span>
  </md-error>
</md-input-container>
```

[**DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/WLdr6ALxHZSAeNk82AfO?p=preview)

Comment: @Swoox you can have many types of errors, like required, pattern, etc. So the `<span>` with `errors.required` is there to specify those error types.